# Prevent Image Blinking

Tags: html, asp.net, css, ajax

The Image Icon blinks On click. So it dissapears & appears like a flash . How Can this be prevented. I tried to fade in & out , to acheive this , but no luck. Any other ideas. (Using c#, Chrome)

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/search.png"
    Width="40px" Height="40px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"/>
   <asp:AnimationExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSearch">
    <Animations>
<OnClick>
 <Sequence>
   <FadeOut Duration="0.3" Fps="30"></FadeOut>
   <FadeIn Duration="0.3" Fps="30"></FadeIn>
 </Sequence>
</OnClick>
    </Animations>
   </asp:AnimationExtender>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use a jpg image not a png.

Comment: Did That. Its the same...